# Proof of a Minkowski Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble proving this.

> Prove that lim$_{p→∞}$ ||**v** ||$_p$ = ||**v**||$_∞$ for any **v**
>   $\in$ $R^2$.

My attempt:

We have that ||**v** ||$_p$ = p (∑||v$_i$||p)^1/2 from the interval of i=1 to infinity,which equals to ||**v** ||$_p$ = (|v$_1$| + |v$_2$| ... + |v$_n$|) but from here on how can I show that it is equal to ||**v**||$_∞$. It seems very obvious it is, but how can I show it formally?

Note: Sorry for my coding format. I am very bad at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that $$n^{1/p} \Vert v \Vert_{\infty} \geq \Vert v \Vert_p \geq \Vert v \Vert_{\infty} \,\,\, (\text{Why?})$$where $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Because if p -> ∞ then all ∥v∥$_p$ = ∥v∥$_∞$ ?

Comment: @diimension Yes.

Comment: Wow, so that keep completes the proof? That simple?